# EF Core Migration Add - creates a migration with unexpected DropForeignKey, DropUniqueConstraint, DropColumn statements

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I made some simple changes on our app that uses EF Core. I just changed the precision of several Decimal typed columns and that is it. When I tried creating a new migration using `dotnet ef migrations add ...` command, I see migration statements I expect to see:

```
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
            name: "Value_Amount",
            schema: "Payment",
            table: "Withdrawals",
            type: "DECIMAL(18, 5)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(decimal),
            oldType: "DECIMAL(15, 2)");
```

Everything looks good apart that it is also showing tons of weird `DropForeignKey`, `DropUniqueConstraint`, `DropColumn` statements. I went through quite a few of them and none of the columns referenced in the `DropX` statements even exist in the Database or model classes. The column names in these `DropX` statements often end in `X_TempId`, `X_TempId1`, etc..

I asked my colleague to checkout (using git) the exact same branch as I have and run the exact same commands (using exact same `dotnet` versions), but his migration is not showing any weird `DropXYZ` statements. Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that `dotnet ef migrations add ...` command compares the current state from the `SomethingModelSnapshot` with the latest state in the Model classes and creates DB changes to get from the current state to the latest one. If this is so, running `dotnet ef migrations add ...` command on the same fileset should always produce the same results, shouldn't it?

Any ideas on what could be happening and/or how to fix this?

Some versions:

```
dotnet --version = 2.2.100
dotnet ef --version = 2.2.0-rtm-35687
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
Windows 10, commands executed via Powershell.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems that this is a bug with EF Core. You can track it here [on their github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14445).

This happened after upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2. But note, that this is not a bug of EF Core 2.2 simply, as recreating a new migration from scratch works beautifully on 2.2, but this is more of a breaking change of interpreting model snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm also using Core 2.2. Was able to get around it by doing a new initial migration. New migrations after that didn't have this problem.

Comment: In case you have a running project to share that reproduces the issue, please do it here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14445